# Imposible to clear cookie Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I try to many options but is imposible delete the cookie. Anyone can help me to understand this.

i try with set maxage , expires , setheaders, nothing deletes the cookie is imposible.

```
res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken,{httpOnly: true, secure: !(process.env.WEB_MODE === "developer"), expires: new Date(Date.now() + expiresIn * 60)})


const logout = (req,res) => {
  res.clearCookie('refreshToken',{ 
    domain: "localhost",       
    path: '/',        
    httpOnly: true,        
    secure: false,        
    sameSite: 'none'    
})
  res.json({ msg: "Successfully logged out" });
}
```

Delete cookies with express.js and res.clearCookie

Comment: From what I read in the docs is that "Web browsers and other compliant clients will only clear the cookie if the given options is identical to those given to res.cookie(), excluding expires and maxAge." From what I can see it seems like they don't have the same options in your code

Comment: If i try with the same config,the same result

Answer (score 0):

The issue goes away when you don't specify `domain` when clearing the cookie:

```
res.clearCookie('refreshToken', {
  path: '/',        
  httpOnly: true,        
  secure: false,        
  sameSite: 'none'    
});
```

Even simpler yet:

```
res.clearCookie('refreshToken', { path: '/' });
```

Here's an [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/keen-euclid-1r4ns8) where you can test `/login`, `/test`, and `/logout` to see the cookie setting, returning and then clearing properly.